# How to bevel a flat surface?

Tags: modeling, bevel

Is it possible to bevel a flat surface using the bevel tool?

Here is my object (a simple ramp):
[image]

and I want to curve this ramp object but the bevel tool doesn't work on flat surfaces:
[image]
[ the bevel tool only create new edges without curves :( ]

The way that I make the curve on the other object has no accurate measurements:
[image]

1. I set the edge bevel weight that be used in bevel modifier;
2. Configure the bevel modifier;
3. I try to position the edge in the exact centre making the other
   adjacent edges the same length.

So, I wanted to use the bevel modifier to avoid manually manipulating the edge position, because I can't position it perfectly.

Comment: Why not creating the curved surface to your liking, **then** model the rest of the object?

Comment: @metaphor_set because if the bevel modifier worked I would save time and could modify the object at any time (_non-destructive modeling_)

Comment: Depending on how much (or less) accuracy you need, the bevel modifier might safe time. It still needs an angle, because otherwise a bevel doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, as @metaphor_set said, makes sense that bevel tool wont work in flat surfaces

> It still needs an angle, because otherwise a bevel doesn't make any sense

so, i go manually:

[image]

this measure addon helps a lot (edit>preferences>addons>"measureit")

### [Edit] I found a new way to do this with exactly precision:

I used an plane as a knife to obtain a vertex at the intersection of the edge that I wanted to snap and now I can use the bevel tool. Here is the workflow:
[image]

### [Edit 2] I found a faster way:

Using "Connect Vertex Path" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) automatically create a new vertex at the intersection of the created edge. Here is the workflow:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the shape to be bevelled first, then use bevel (ctrl-b) on that middle edge..
[image]

[image]

Comment: that is what I am doing, however, I need precise measures. as i showed in figure 3, i can get approximate results, but i wanted perfect measures. the bevel tool is the only tool I know for making curves from edges